# Is there a manometer available to use with Arduino?

Tags: pressure

I used an analog manometer in a plumb system. I would like to actually track information about water pressure across an entire building on different points and record all this information to analyze changes on pressure. I was wondering if there is a manometer that can be used with arduino. Or if there is some other homemade solution?

If there is any electronic sensor with an analog output that would be enough.

Comment: There are intrusive ones, i.e. you need to cut the pipes.  I can't say I have seen one that you could just wrap around the pipe, but the should exist.  I doubt you find one specifically for Arduinos, but you should be able to get one that the Arduino can talk to, look for I2C, SPI or One wire interfaces.  If you can get the datasheet it should be simple enough to write your own library for it.  Looking for libraries is another way of identifying a suitable part.

Comment: @CodeGorilla Yeah I was planning to cut the pipe, I already used an analog one cutting the pipe. Thanks for the advice, I will start looking for I2C and SPI One wire interfaces.

Comment: glue a neodymium magnet to the analog meter's needle, then mount a hall-effect sensor on the side of the meter and read it's value to determine pressure. you could also go optical.

Comment: I think the problem is not the way to connect a manometer but the choice od the manometer. I work on project for Firefighters and my main problem is to find flow meters able to measure flow between 0 and 1000 liters per minutes, and manoter for pressure up to 25 bars and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bruno, there are a number of sensors available, try an Ebay search, to do what you want.  However, you need to determine what pressure range you are looking at.  As you mention manometer I assume you are working in the mBar range but to me that would be at odds with the pressure typically seen in whole building systems.  An Ebay search on 'Pressure transducers' will yield a good range of devices, likely to be primarily industrial types and some using wheatstone bridge type outputs.  you may need an op-amp circuit to buffer / amplify the output signal but virtually all sensors can be interfaced to an Arduino with the correct conditioning cicuitry.  As you are aware to measure pressure all sensors will need to be invasive into the pipework.